# Can $target_path be renamed?

Tags: php, upload

I'm creating form that has multiple uploads, and I'm wondering if I can rename the `$target_path` function, or if it's set in PHP stone. For example, if I wanted to call the target path for document A `$doca_path` and the path for Document B `$docb_path`. Is that allowed?

Comment: There is no such function in PHP. Also, function names cannot start with `$`.

Comment: Er, what? `$target_path` is a variable, not a function. You could always try changing it and see what happens....

Comment: My bad for calling it a function. I just wanted to know if it absolutely has to be named target_path. But now that I know it's a variable, I guess I'll give calling it other things a shot.

Comment: @SyrupandSass you look good you should hit me up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Variables in PHP are represented by a dollar sign followed by the name of the variable. The variable name is case-sensitive.

`$target_path` is a variable, not a function.

In some file upload scripts variables are named `$target_path` like so:

```
$target_path = "uploads/";    
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
```

It simply denotes the destination folder. You can change it to whatever you want. It can be `$path_target`, `$target`, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember You can can set `$target_path` in `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)` to whatever path You want. Only 3 things:

1. You have right permissions to write to target directory.
2. All the directory tree to `$target_path` is already created.
3. Also, according http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php You should be aware of `safe_mode` and `open_basedir` restrictions.